# Deleted messages saves in log channel but no files - Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i'm having troubles with my Discord bot
I've made a simple system to save deleted messages in a channel, it saves every message in embed.
Here's my code:

```
client.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
    if(messageDelete.content === Discord.MessageEmbed){
        messageDelete.content === 'embed'
    }
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("PURPLE")
    .setDescription("A new message has been filtered")
    .setAuthor(`${messageDelete.author.tag}`, `${messageDelete.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true})}`)
    .setThumbnail(messageDelete.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic : true}))        
    .addFields(
        {name: "Message Deleted:", value: `${messageDelete.content}`, inline: true},
        {name: "Channel Founded:", value: `${messageDelete.channel}`, inline: true},
        {name: "User Author:", value: `${messageDelete.author.tag}`, inline: true}
    )
    .setFooter(`The message may be deleted by the user or a bot.`)
    .setTimestamp()
    client.channels.cache.get('723005913841008662').send(embed);
});
```

The bot is working correctly, saves every message in the channel but when i delete a file, like an image or video, it sents and error message:

```
if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
                ^
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

I'm just having this trouble and i don't really know solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because if there is only an attachment, `message.content` will return undefined, and it will give an error. You should use the logical OR operator (`||`) to dodge any errors if `message.content` isn't defined.

```js
.addFields(
  { 
     name: "Message Deleted:", 
     value: messageDelete.content || 'There was no message content', 
     inline: true 
  },
  {
     name: "Channel Founded:", 
     value: messageDelete.channel, 
     inline: true
  },
  {
     name: "User Author:", 
     value: messageDelete.author.tag, 
     inline: true
   }
)
```

Comment: Very thankful answer, it's working now. Thank you very much.